# Register Tumblr app for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, tumblr, xauth

I registered an app on the Tumblr developer website for my iPhone app. The app need to upload a photo to Tumblr with tags and caption and it's running normally. However, the photo after uploaded on Tumblr does not show my iPhone app name below the photo. It just shows the caption, tags under the photo. As Diptic (iPhone app) or Instagram, I see there is an app icon and a link to its app homepage under the uploaded photo.

I'm wondering is there anything wrong when I registered the app on Tumblr developer page or my iPhone app client missed something?

P/S: My iPhone app is using xAuth.

Thank you for reading my question. If you aren't clear anything, just let me know.

Regards,
Tien

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload your app photo in 24 bit PNG format with 128x128 pixels.
You will see the app icon if you success. You can try to save this 128x128 PNG from different apps, or you can try to save PNG in 8 bit format.